Bayesian estimation of a Gamma distribution with stan
I am struggling with make the code work.
I have some panel data for different firms in different years. I checked the data and it looks very much like a Gamma distribution. I wanted to check if estimating a Gamma from my data would give a good fit, good r_hat and chains mixing well.
The problem is: I estimated a model where I have a single alpha and a single beta for the entire distribution, so all years have the same alpha and beta. I would like to estimate an alpha and a beta for each year, so I could see how they evolve over time.
Could you please help me understand where I am doing something incorrect and how to fix it?
Thank you in advance!
The code that is NOT incorporating the years and that works fine is:
# Define variable to work with
y_wr <- d3$wr

# Define Stan model for Bayesian estimation
stan_code_wr <- "
data {
  int<lower=0> N;
  vector[N] y;
}
parameters {
  real<lower=0> alpha;
  real<lower=0> beta;
}
model {
  alpha ~ gamma(1, 1);
  beta ~ gamma(1, 1);
  y ~ gamma(alpha, beta);
}
generated quantities {
  real mean_profit;
  real variance_profit;
  
  mean_profit = alpha / beta;
  variance_profit = alpha / (beta * beta);
}
"
# Run Stan model for gamma estimation
samples_gamma_wr <- stan(model_code = stan_code_wr, 
                         data = list(N = length(y_wr), y = y_wr), 
                         iter = 20000, warmup = 1000, chains = 4)


I tried to make it work for yearly alpha and beta and the chains either take forever to run or do not run at all (I tried MANY ways to code it).
My last attempt looks like:
stan_code_yearly <- "
data {
  int<lower=0> N;
  int<lower=0> num_years;
  int<lower=1, upper=num_years> year[N];
  vector[N] y;
}
parameters {
  vector<lower=0>[num_years] alpha;
  vector<lower=0>[num_years] beta;
}
model {
  for (j in 1:num_years) {
    alpha[j] ~ gamma(1, 1);
    beta[j] ~ gamma(1, 1);
  }
  for (i in 1:N) {
    y[i] ~ gamma(alpha[year[i]], beta[year[i]]);
  }
}
generated quantities {
  vector[num_years] mean_profit;
  vector[num_years] variance_profit;
  
  for (j in 1:num_years) {
    mean_profit[j] = alpha[j] / beta[j];
    variance_profit[j] = alpha[j] / (beta[j] * beta[j]);
  }
}
"

# Run Stan model for gamma estimation
samples_gamma_yearly <- stan(model_code = stan_code_yearly, 
                             data = list(N = length(y_wr), num_years = max(year_wr), year = year_wr, y = y_wr), 
                             iter = 10000, warmup = 1000, chains = 3)


You'll probably have better luck asking on the stan forums.
